# How can I generate a matrix M, where its covariance is the Identity matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, identity, covariance

How can I generate a matrix `M` such that `cov(M) = I` (identity). I use matlab to generate M.

Comment: You would probably get better answers on [the math site](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `M` is made up of columns `m1,m2,...mN`, and `x1=(m1-mean(m1))/sqrt(N-1)` then `cov(M)=X'*X`

This means `cov(M)=I` iff `X` is an orthonormal matrix. You can use this fact to design `X` and then work your way back to an `M`

Comment: I think I can use PCA transformation to generate an orthonormal matrix, but I'm not sure how to generate it in Matlab

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/princomp.html

Comment: Would you please show me an example. However I know your answer is correct, but I cannot reproduce it in Matlab, For example please let me a 3x3 matrix with cov=I

Comment: I don't know too much about PCA, but the link above has links to other Matlab functions like `pcacov` or `pca` and there is also a function called `orth` that may help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23105/discussion-between-remo-and-user1860611)